# Add another Select-list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, select, dynamic

I'm having a drop down list and once the user change the default option value = "" (on Change) to something else in the list, I would like the form to append the same drop down list again with a different name +1 or something similar with a possibility to add unlimited numbers of drop down... I'm planning to use it to build a list of tags dynamically.

This is a similar script I found that is working with input type="text" 
http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

```
    $(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});

    <h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>
    <div id="p_scents">
    <p>
    <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
    </div>
```

I would like actually to find out how to do the same, except I would like to add a drop down list rather then an input text...

Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

thx

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Yes, Im using a modified version of Scott and it's all working now... I could not use jQuery UI 1.9.1... it's working fine with 1.7.1 for this part of my application :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change what's added to a select list....

```
 <label for="p_scnts"><select id="p_scnt"  name="p_scnt_' + i +'"><option value="">ONE</option><option value="">TWO</option></select></label>
```

**[Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/tZPg4/5132/)**

Comment: Genius! Exactly what I was looking for... and so fast... Thanks a lot guys :) <3

Comment: For some reason, Im trying the code as it is and it's not working :( it's throwing me at the top of the browser # and no list added... Im using jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: It works in the fiddle... you must not have altered something properly.

Comment: it's working with jQuery 1.7.1... so im loading 1.7.1 for this part of this application... thanks a lot for your help, this script is perfect to do what I need.  <3

Comment: Your fiddle was set to jquery 1.4 and it works. Must be some other error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, It will help you...

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/5136/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divselection"> 
<p>
 <select class="target">
  <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
 </select>
</p>
<div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).on("change", ".target", function(){
    $("#divselection").html($("#divselection").html() + "<p><select class='target'>" + $(this).html() + "</select><a href='#' id='remScnt'>Remove</a></p>");
});    

$(document).on("click", "#remScnt", function(){
    $(this).parents('p').remove();
});
```

Comment: it seems on change is not a good idea finally... if the user change back the first list, it will create a new list... the add button will finally be the best option. Thank a lot for your answer :)